# How to write a list to a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I have a list that has data as following:

```
[[a,b,1], [c,d,3], [a,c,2], [c,d,1]]
```

How can I write this list of lists to a csv file?

I tried this, but it did not work.

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write((list))
```

Comment: use the built-in CSV module: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

[`csvwriter.writerows()`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows)