# how to write back to open csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to go through a csv file, validate zip codes and write the city and state to the last column in the csv file.

I managed to get the csv data and get the city and state, but I don't understand how to write the new data to the last column.  SO examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372705/how-to-write-a-list-to-a-csv-file) show how to create a csv, but not work with an existing csv.

here is my code so far:

```
with open("propertyOutput.csv", "rbw") as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp, skipinitialspace=True)
    table = [row for row in reader]
    for rows in table:
        stringNeed = rows['zip']
        if not stringNeed.isdigit(): 
            print"not number"  #would like to write this to the column
            pass
        else:
            if not len(stringNeed) == 5:  
                print"string not 5 long"  # would like to write this to the column
            else:
                x = getCityState(stringNeed)
                print x  # would like to write this to the column
```

Comment: I guess it is better to write everything in new file with added info than editing the open file. and I don't think their is any way to insert in the middle except rewrite whole file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do it in two steps:

1. Read the csv file and store information

   ```
   import csv

   with open("propertyOutput.csv", "rbw") as fp:
       reader = csv.DictReader(fp, skipinitialspace=True)
       table = [row for row in reader]
       header = reader.fieldnames
   ```
2. Write the information to an new file or replace old file

   ```
   with open("propertyOutput.csv", "wb") as fp:
       writer = csv.DictWriter(fp, header)
       for row in table:
           if not stringNeed.isdigit(): 
               rows['zip'] = "not number"
           # even more stuff to check and edit here
           # write the edited row
           writer.writerow(row)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Files, in general, do not support the concept of "insertion". You can only delete them, overwrite them (that is, either replace the file entirely, or replace a certain number of bytes with exactly the same number of (different) bytes), or append to them.

So to change the contents of a CSV file, you will have to overwrite it (the good news is, the CSV module makes it pretty easy).