# Get column value using column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
    production_type       type_a       type_b     type_c     type_d     
0             type_a     1.173783    0.714846    0.583621        1
1             type_b     1.418876    0.864110    0.705485        1
2             type_c     1.560452    0.950331    0.775878        1
3             type_d     1.750531    1.066091    0.870388        1
4             type_a     1.797883    1.094929    0.893932        1
5             type_a     1.461784    0.890241    0.726819        1
6             type_b     0.941938    0.573650    0.468344        1
7             type_a     0.507370    0.308994    0.252271        1
8             type_c     0.443565    0.270136    0.220547        1
9             type_d     0.426232    0.259579    0.211928        1
10            type_d     0.425379    0.259060    0.211504        1
```

I would like to create a new column, list or series to that return the value of the column.

OUTPUT

```
    production_type       type_a       type_b     type_c     type_d     Results 
0             type_a     1.173783    0.714846    0.583621        1     1.173783    
1             type_b     1.418876    0.864110    0.705485        1     0.864110    
2             type_c     1.560452    0.950331    0.775878        1     0.775878        
3             type_d     1.750531    1.066091    0.870388        1     1
4             type_a     1.797883    1.094929    0.893932        1     1.797883
5             type_a     1.461784    0.890241    0.726819        1     1.461784
6             type_b     0.941938    0.573650    0.468344        1     0.573650
```

Basically if its written type_a in the column [production_type] I want to return the results of type_a in a column [Results].

Ive tried the following :

```
for i in df:
    if i == 'type_a':
        print ('type_a')
    elif i == 'type_b':
        print ('type_b')
    elif i == 'type_c':
        print ('type_c')
    elif i == 'type_d':
        print ('type_d')
    else:
        print('')  
    print('')
```

using result.append

To generate the dataframe use the following :

```
list_cols = ['type_a','type_b','type_c']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), columns = list_cols )
df['production_type']= ['type_a','type_b','type_c','type_d','type_a','type_a','type_b'
                       ,'type_b','type_c','type_d']
 df['type_d'] = 1
 df['results'] = ''
```

Any hint on where to search?

Comment: Can you add this dataframe as numpy arrays using df.values in your question. It would be easier to use that to create dataframe on my machine instead of just typing it.

Comment: 1. Read the csv file, 2. Calculate the results, 3. Write a new csv file. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20336519/1251007

Comment: Well I don't have your csv file

Comment: There is no csv file. I update the question to make it easier for you to backtest. 2 sec

Comment: @jat Ctrl+C the dataframe, then use `df = pd.read_clipboard()`

Comment: @jpp thanks for feedback. df.apply with the lambda really helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.apply` for this:

```
df['Results'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.get(row['production_type']), axis=1)
```

**Explanation**

- `pd.DataFrame.apply` with `axis=1` applies a function to each row and extracts, via an implicit loop, the components of each row.
- The method allows an anonymous `lambda` function as an argument.
- We can define the `lambda` function to extract the required value from `production_type` column.

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
result = list()
index =0
for i in df['production_type']:
    value = df[i][index]
    index = index+1
    result.append(value)

df['Results'] = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` method by passing a `lambda` function.

```
df['Results'] = df.index.map(lambda index : df[df['production_type'][index]][index])
```