# write a Python 3 list to .csv

Tags: list, csv, python-3.x

I have a list that i need to write to a .csv   Yes, i have done a LOT of looking around (of course i found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372705/how-to-write-a-list-to-a-csv-file) which is close to the target, but misses my case) You see `writerows` is having all sorts of trouble with the delimiters/formatting in the .csv (the **a** gets separated from the **1** from the **7** etc etc)

My list looks like this:

`buffer = [['a17', 'b17', 'c17', '8', 'e17', 'f17\n'], ['a24', 'b24', 'c24', '6', 'e24', 'f24\n'], ['a27', 'b27', 'c27', '9', 'e27', 'f27\n'], ['a18', 'b18', 'c18', '9', 'e18', 'f18\n'], ['a5', 'b5', 'c5', '5', 'e5', 'f5\n'], ['a20', 'b20', 'c20', '2', 'e20', 'f20\n'], ['a10', 'b10', 'c10', '1', 'e10', 'f10\n'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', '3', 'e3', 'f3\n'], ['a11', 'b11', 'c11', '2', 'e11', 'f11\n']]`

I can see its like a list of lists so i tried `for eachRow in buffer:` then following on with a `eachRow.split(',')` but no good there either.
I just need to write to a .csv it should be easy right... what am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the \n string from your buffer like so. Also you have to add `newline=''` to the with statement in Python 3. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16716489/1519290) for more detail.

```
import csv


buffer = [['a17', 'b17', 'c17', '8', 'e17', 'f17\n'],
          ['a24', 'b24', 'c24', '6', 'e24', 'f24\n'],
          ['a27', 'b27', 'c27', '9', 'e27', 'f27\n'],
          ['a18', 'b18', 'c18', '9', 'e18', 'f18\n'],
          ['a5', 'b5', 'c5', '5', 'e5', 'f5\n'],
          ['a20', 'b20', 'c20', '2', 'e20', 'f20\n'],
          ['a10', 'b10', 'c10', '1', 'e10', 'f10\n'],
          ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', '3', 'e3', 'f3\n'],
          ['a11', 'b11', 'c11', '2', 'e11', 'f11\n']]

for row_index, list in enumerate(buffer):
    for column_index, string in enumerate(list):
        buffer[row_index][column_index] = buffer[row_index][column_index].replace('\n', '')

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(buffer)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv
with open('output.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(buffer)
```

Note that the last entry in each of your lists has a newline, so the csvwriter is correctly quoting the string so you end up with `"f17\n"` (in the first list as an example) which will look strangely formatted if you are not expecting a new line.

Comment: i can't believe i was so close. you are great!  That's a cool start and as you suggested the newlines are adding blank rows. So what do you suggest is the cleanest way to get rid of the `\n` newlines? (They just seem to be there when i read the source .csv file)

Comment: I tried `lineAsList = [i.strip() for i in a]` which removes the `\n`s from `buffer` but the .csv STILL has every second row blank... any thoughts?

Comment: I addressed your question in my answer.